# Div take full height in a containing div (background)

Tags: html, sticky-footer, css

I have the following problem.

I am using a twitter bootstrap to make my new website but I have difficulties with the background. The following is what I have :

```
<body>   
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
               ...
        </div>
        <div id="header">
             ...
        </div>
        <div id="content">
             ...
        </div>
        <div class="push>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
         ....
    </div>
</body>
```

The navbar is fixed at top. (fixed height)
The header (title stuff) is scrolling with the page and is fixed height.
the footer is at the bottom of the page but scrolls if there is more content (not fixed at bottom but fixed height)

What I want is that the content has a background that takes all the avaiable space (from right after the header till the footer) 
[Image to clarify](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/600/capturevxb.png/)

[Full HTML & CSS(without bootstrap css) code](http://pastebin.com/81ks2g80)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the content area to be at least 100% less header and footer so to speak?

This is how i would do it:

demo:
http://jsbin.com/ofijap/1/edit

```
.head {
  height:100px;
  background-color:green;
}
.wrap {
  min-height:100%;
  background-color:red;
}
.footer {
  height:100px;
  background-color:grey;
  margin-top:-100px;
}
.content {
  padding-bottom:100px;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
      <div class="head">Head</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>   
    </div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

as a rule of thumb, if you want something to fill up all the vertical space it probably needs min-height:100%; But, its parent should have 100% height too, and so on up to the body element.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ipecuc/1/edit this is what I get in your paste bin, but in my asp.net MVC4 website it does not take the full height for the 'white' part. Also in jsbin you get more content than your screen. image: http://www.sharepic.org/public/view/full/171

Comment: use the red part for styling, not the white part. set the white part where actual content is to transparent, use the red element for styling

Comment: so how should I make the center part white then? but still keeping the red in the margins left and right(they are variable to screen size and will nog keep at 100px)

Comment: the div which is red, set to margin:0 100px; make it white, set body to red, or grey or whatever. Assuming 100px is the left and right margin of the white content area

Answer (score 0):

To the people who want to see my final result: thanks to @user1721135 ;)
http://jsbin.com/udoxet/2/edit

Now I'm gonna try and port it to my own website see if that works :)